# Converting String to Int C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert an inputted string to an int. I have tried **int.parse**, and **int.parse32** but when I press "enter" I get the following error:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, 
                                  NumberBuffer & number...."
```

partial class Form1:

```
this.orderID.Text = currentID;
this.orderID.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(EnterKey);
```

partial class Form1:Form:

```
  public int newCurrentID;
  private void EnterKey(object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            try
            {
                newCurrentID = int.Parse(currentID);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a break point to method `EnterKey` and see what `currentID` contains.

Comment: What type is currentID and what is its content?

Comment: what do u find inside currentID just when u parse it

Comment: Are you relying on the fact that you set currentID at the top of the class? This wont pick up changes to currentID and will/may be empty when the form loads. Try getting the value from the control directly; for example, `Int.TryParse(orderID.Text, out someInt);`

Comment: also int.tryparse can be used which I recall was faster internally

Comment: You don't show code where the value of `orderID.Text` is copied into `currentID`. You do have that, don't you?

Comment: this.orderID.Text = currentID; is blank. the user will input a value here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String is immutable so when you assign `currentID` to the textbox any changes of that text will not be reflected in the variable `currentID`

```
this.orderID.Text = currentID;
```

What you need to do in the `EnterKey` function is to use the Textbox value directly:

```
private void EnterKey(object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        { 
            if(!int.TryParse(orderID.Text, out newCurrentID))
               MessageBox.Show("Not a number");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out alot, and taught me a new thing as well. :)

Answer (score 4):

Check string for `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` and do not try to parse such strings.

Comment: I'd like to mention the newer `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` method (since C# 4.0), does some extra checking for the user :).

Answer (score 1):

Use `TryParse` instead of parse the value directly:

```
int intResult = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse(yourString, out intResult) == true)
{
    // do whatever you want...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentID)){
     newCurrentID = int.Parse(currentID);
}
```